# Como trabaja un marketplace con las rutas amigables

Tags: javascript, php, mvc, .htaccess, rutas

El modelo vista controlador trabaja segun lo que pidas en la url(namepagina/controller/method/param). Pero en un marketplace si quiero ver un producto en la url solo te muestra (namepagina/nombre-del-producto) y no como yo lo hago (namepagina/store/producto/nombre-del producto) primero poniendo la url de la pagina (namepagina) depues el controlador(store) despues el metodo(producto) y al final parametro(nombre-del producto). Como puedo reducir la url a (namepagina/nombre-del-producto).

He estado investigando sobre el tema MVC y rutas amigables, pero la informaciones lo que ya se. No me dan mas informacion de lo que busco

Comment: Hola carlos! bastante interesante tu pregunta, hay muchos metodos que se pueden hacer con RewriteRule y las vistas que asignemos en dado caso que se detecte un parametro. El tema es que no es recomendable el hecho de manejar solamente `domain.com/lechedecoco`  por temas de las mismas rutas que en un futuro se pueden truncar o tengamos que re enrutar. lo que si puedes hacer es `domain.com/producto/lechedecoco` y quedaria mas ordenado visualmente. Te puedo tambien recomendar mejorar la UIX para que hagas que el usuario llegue mas rapido al producto, que al parecer es lo que buscas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta esta en el `.htaccess`
Basicamente lo que debes hacer es convertir las url amigables  a rutas que tu sistema pueda interpretar.

Ejemplo:
Para la ruta

```
 www.mitienda.com/es/tienda/producto/ordenador-sobremesa/e-10/
```

Debes escribir las siguiente regla

```html
 RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/tienda/producto/[^/]+/e-([0-9]+)/?$  /controlles/method/ver.php?idioma=$1&idProducto=$2  [L,NC]
```

Puesdes utilizar la [herramienta online](https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/) para probar reglas